# How to insert div after other div with if else condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to move div after another div, if outer div's width is less then 800

```js
$(function() {
  if ($('.main').width() < "800 px") {
    $(".one").insertBefore($(".two"));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main" style="overflow: hidden; border:solid 1px red; text-align: right; ">
  <div class="two" style="background-color: #ccc; margin: 2px; padding: 10px; float: right; width:500px;">buttons</div>
  <div class="one" style="background-color: #ccc; margin: 2px; padding: 10px; float: right; width:300px;">dropdown</div>

</div>
```

Comment: [Making decisions in your code — conditionals - Learn web development | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/conditionals)

Comment: Why are you not using CSS Grid or Flex for this? This isn't something that should require JavaScript (except for legacy browsers, perhaps). Also, please stop with inline styles (it makes your code harder to read and follow).

Comment: @DavidThomas Thanks for your suggestion. Could you please show me how can I achieve it with CSS?

Comment: Can you clearly describe what layout you're starting with, and how you want to adjust it? Ideally a couple of (simple) pictures? Incidentally, while I, and others, am happy to help you first need to try to solve the problem yourself (there should be some ideas here on Stack Overflow), try those approaches. If you can't work it out, or the code doesn't do what you expect it to do, then feel free to come back and [edit] your question with the new information. Incidentally, while you research and try I would suggest deleting this question temporarily to avoid further down-, and close-, votes.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't understand the string `"800 px"`, it requires just the number `800`.

Also, like others mentioned, try to keep your styles in css and not inline if you're using classes, it's easier to follow along with the code and edit the code in the future.

```js
$(function() {
  if ($('.main').outerWidth(true) < 800) {
    $(".one").insertBefore($(".two"));
  }
});
```

```css
.main {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid 1px red;
  text-align: right;
}

.two {
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 10px;
  float: right;
  width: 500px;
}

.one {
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 10px;
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="two">buttons</div>
  <div class="one">dropdown</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Its working. Only thing is I need to refresh the page. Can it be done only if I resize the browser. I am looking this for responsive website

Comment: @VishalDevrukhkar You can refresh the page by using `location.reload()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload inside of a click event.

Comment: @VishalDevrukhkar Would you mind accepting this as the answer if it worked for you?